# Which linux distro is based on Arch, runs LXDE and out of the box ready to use?

Tags: linux, distribution-choice

Besides that, have full multimedia, driver, network and essential software support?

Comment: It's an ongoing argument, but if you want a complete distro, which choose Arch? One chooses Arch to install what is needed, and no more, from the base, upwards. That allows one to learn which packages are needed, optional, and to some extent, what the system is like before/after installing each package. Yes, it's time consuming ... :)

Comment: Are you aware that you can select any distro you like (that includes LXDE packages) and just install the relevant packages?

Comment: @bdowning That is _one_ reason to choose Arch but it would be foolish to say it's the only reason to choose Arch.  It would be good for the OP to mention why they want the distro to be based on Arch though.  Is it the wiki that they like?  The fact that it's rolling release?  The community?  These would be good things to know to help suggest an alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None.

See also:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_Based_Distributions_%28Active%29

Answer (score 1):

I think it's too late to answer, but anyway... The distro, you're looking for is "Manjaro Linux", community edition.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/manjarolinux/files/community/LXDE/

Comment: Nice hint for a lightweight distribution!